# How to fill NSMutableArray with images from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, image, parse-platform

Hello I need to fill a **NSMutableArray with images from parse.com** can anyone please help

```
patternImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"neon-autumn.gif", @"alchemy.jpg", @"white-wood.jpg", @"green-goblin.png", @"subway-lines.png", @"canvas-orange.jpg", @"kiwis.png", @"cuadros.png", @"hodgepodge.png", @"naranjas.png", @"bunting-flag.png", nil];
```

I need to display the images from my database in **Parse.com**

Comment: You should save ImageURL and download each image separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the url from the PFFile using `file.url`, then create an image using that url, and add each image to your array.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:file.url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
```

Comment: You should write the code avoiding 'dataWithContentsOfURL:'. It lokcs the main thread, try to use asynchronous download the images separately as suggested by @Suhail